# Lower bound on the intersection of $\ell_1$ $n$-balls

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, computational-geometry, norms

Let $B_1$ and $B_2$ be two balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$ in $\ell_1$ norm, with distance $d$ and radius $R$.

Is there a **lower** bound on the volume of the intersection between the two n-balls? (assuming the balls are relatively close, and in particular, $R>d/2$)

(In $\ell_2$ norm it's possible to get the lower bound by looking at the $n$-dimensional cylinder in the intersection, but the analogue to $\ell_1$ norm wasn't clear to me).